# Как создать Pageable для сортировки по вложенному свойству?

Tags: java, spring, сортировка, spring-data-jpa

Имеется две сущности: **Cat** и **Kitty** *(не обращайте внимание на отсутствие некоторых аннотаций, это всего лишь пример)*:

```
public class Cat {
    
    int id;

    String name;

    int age;

    @OneToOne
    Kitty kitty;
}


public class Kitty {

    int id;

    String name;

    @OneToOne
    Cat cat;
}
```

Я реализовал **JpaRepository** для сущности **Cat** и теперь хочу получать списки котов, используя при этом сортировку:

```
public interface CatRepository extends JpaRepository<Cat, Integer> {
    
    @Query("SELECT c FROM Cat c WHERE c.age=:age")
    List<Cat> getAllByAge(int age, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Насколько видно, я передаю в метод объект **Pageable**, который используется для сортировки. Собственно, вот возник вопрос. Например, если я хочу сделать сортировку по имени кота, я создаю **Pageable** таким образом:

```
PageRequest.of(pageNum, pageSize, direction, "name");
```

А что, если я хочу сделать сортировку, допустим, по имени *котёнка*? Я бы сделал вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT c FROM Cat c WHERE c.age=:age ORDER BY c.kitty.name
```

Вот только запрос - штука неповоротливая. Именно поэтому я и использую **Pageable**, и как мне его в таком случае создать? Будет ли работать такой вариант:

```
PageRequest.of(pageNum, pageSize, direction, "kitty.name");
```

И если это не будет работать, то как мне тогда можно сортировку по вложенному свойству?

Comment: Должно работать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, для создания `Pageable` можно использовать вложенные свойства. К сожалению я не знаю тонкостей и не знаю, как именно интерпретируется `Pageable`, но вот [здесь на Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query) приводится пример правильного составления запроса с countQuery для версии `Spring Data JPA` до 2.0.4:

```
@Query(
  value = "SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY id \n-- #pageable\n",
  countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM Users",
  nativeQuery = true)
Page<User> findAllUsersWithPagination(Pageable pageable);
```

Исходя из этого могу предположить, что сначала JPQL запрос дополняется данными из `Pageable`, а только потом конвертируется в SQL запрос. Скорее всего поэтому вложенные свойства в `Pageable` и работают. Но на самом деле это только моё предположения и я был бы признателен, если бы кто-нибудь пояснил, как это работает на самом деле.